# How to insert "\|" into dot file created by graphviz.sty package

Tags: pdftex, dot2tex

I am trying to get (without quotes) "\|" to appear in the dot file produced by the graphviz latex package. To clarify, I want my DOT file contents to be something like

```
digraph junk {
  node [shape=record];
  n1 [label="{ A | B\|C }"];
}
```

This would produce an image like

[image: Desired output]

In particular, I need to escape the pipe symbol to avoid creating a new cell in the record. Any thoughts on how to make this happen? Here is my setup so far:

**f.tex:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdf]{graphviz}
\begin{document}
\digraph[]{junk}{
  node [shape=record];
  n1 [label="{ A | B\|C }"];
}
\end{document}
```

**Compile:**

```
$ pdflatex -shell-escape f.tex
$ pdflatex f.tex
```

**Produces DOT file:**

```
digraph junk {
  node [shape=record];
  n1 [label="{ A | B\delimiter "026B30D C }"];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass to GraphViz the string `\|`

The easiest way is to define a `\pipe` command

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdf]{graphviz}

\edef\pipe{\string\|}

\begin{document}

\digraph[]{junk}{
  node [shape=record];
  n1 [label="{ A | B\pipe C }"];
}

\end{document}
```

More complicated, but allows typing `\|`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdf]{graphviz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% consider \| unexpandable; it happens in a group, so nothing bad happens
\pretocmd{\@@digraph}{\let\|\relax}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\digraph[]{junk}{
  node [shape=record];
  n1 [label="{ A | B\|C }"];
}

\end{document}
```

It would probably make sense that the `graphviz` package defines a list of “escaped characters” to not be interpreted when writing of the `.dot` file.

[image]