# How to make a literal backslash in the digraph pacakge?

Tags: graphs, shell-escape

I'm trying to use the backslash `\` character in one of my node names in the digraph package:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphviz}

\begin{document}
\digraph[scale=0.5]{abc}{
rankdir=LR; 
"\\x"->"y";
}
\end{document}
```

The code is valid graphviz (tried on [WebGraphViz](http://webgraphviz.com/)). Removing the `\\` makes it compile fine.

But when I include the backslashes, I get a confusing error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
\\  ->\let \reserved@e 
                       \relax \let \reserved@f \relax \@ifstar {\let \reserv...
l.7 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same idea as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227287/4427

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[pdf]{graphviz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% consider \| and \\ unexpandable; it happens in a group, so nothing bad happens
\pretocmd{\@@digraph}
  {%
   \let\|\relax % allow \|
   \let\\\relax % allow \\
  }{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\digraph[scale=0.5]{abc}{
rankdir=LR;
"\\x"->"y";
}
\end{document}
```

The contents of `abc.dot` will be

```
digraph abc {
rankdir=LR;
"\\x"->"y";
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphviz}

\begin{document}
\digraph[scale=0.5]{abc}{
rankdir=LR; 
"\string\\x"->"y";
}
\end{document}
```